# How do I perform an InOrder traversal of this tree and print out each element?

Tags: python

I wrote this code for a BTree but I need to perform an InOrder traversal of the tree and print out each element as it traverses the tree. This is the code for the BTree. I excluded the code for insertion and deletion as it's not important here.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, leaf=False):
        self.leaf = leaf
        self.keys = []
        self.child = []

class BTree:
    def __init__(self, t):
        self.root = Node(True)
        self.t = t
    
#code for insert and delete
```

I understand how to do it if it was like this:

```
class Node: 
    def __init__(self,key): 
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.val = key 

    def printInorder(root): 
        if root: 
            printInorder(root.left) 
            print(root.val), 
            printInorder(root.right) 

root = Node(1) 
root.left      = Node(2) 
root.right     = Node(3) 
root.left.left  = Node(4) 
root.left.right  = Node(5) 

printInorder(root)
```

But I'm not sure how to apply this to my code.

Comment: What have you tried yourself? What problems did you run into?

Comment: if `s` stands for `self`, please use `self` instead - brevity has its limit, and you found it!

Comment: I haven't really tried anything of significance. Not sure where to start.

Comment: yes s stand for self. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: What is `t`? Can you provide a sample tree so we don't have to construct one?

Comment: Do you know what an in-order traversal is?  Do you know what a recursive function is?  Usually the reason for asking the kind of question you have asked is due to a lack of understanding of the fundamentals, or an unwillingness to make an attempt.  Don't be afraid to get it wrong.  It's code.  You're not writing control software for a nuclear power plant.  Nothing is going to explode or melt down.

Comment: @paddy Yes I know what they are, I'm just not sure how to apply them to my code.

Comment: Draw your tree on paper, then start at the root, and decide what an in-order traversal "looks like".  Perform logical steps at each node to work out what values should be printed out.  Keep track of your "stack" by writing down which nodes are currently being processed by recursive calls, and where they are at in their "execution".  If you can't conceptually visualize what your program should do, you really have no chance of actually writing code to make it do that.